# Assign country IP to another continent

Tags: ip, ip-address

I'm not sure I'm in the right place, I'm still trying.

How would it be possible to assign a public IP provided by the entity providing them (`RIR`?) to a server/router in another continent?

I don't know much about how IP assignation work (how it gets to my router at home for instance), but often, ISPs allow a user to choose the "country" assigned to a failover IP for a dedicated server. I would like to know if it's possible to do it inter-continent, if so, how could I proceed please (which entity to contact first, etc...).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISP to which you connect must agree to advertise and route any addressing which you use, regardless of continent. If the ISP owns the address in question, this may be easy, but if the ISP doesn't own the address, you will need to connect to the ISP using BGP, and the ISP will not advertise any prefix longer than `/24` for IPv4 or `/48` for IPv6.

Comment: Well, thank you for your quick answer. First of all, I need to get an IP address (`/29` or `/30` should be enough to begin with), who do I need to contact? AFRINIC (for African IPs)? Then, I will have to contact my ISP, am I right?

Comment: The RIRs have run out of IPv4 addresses to assign. It used to be that companies could get ISP-independent addresses from the RIR, but no longer for IPv4; you can get ISP-independent IPv6 addressing from the RIRs. You will need to get your addresses from the ISP that you will use.

Comment: @Max13, just to make sure you understand, even if you had an independent `/29` or `/30` prefix, an ISP which doesn't own the `/24` block to which it belongs would not advertise it because it is longer than `/24`. The Internet routing table is far too large to advertise every little network anyone may have.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. I didn't understand "longer" that way, I thought you were talking about "availability range". Anyway, it might be hard indeed, but I'm in Congo (Republic Of), the problem is that local ISPs don't use much IPv4 addresses (mostly, they share an IPv4 between customers) and don't route IPv6 at all because it's "too expensive and not widely used". I guess they missed the "exhaustion" problem... AFRINIC seems to have few `/8` I guess. I have few phone calls to do and will come back to you

Answer (score 0):

No.  But what you can do is get a circuit in country you want to talk from and then from that circuit, you can tunnel/route all the traffic to a different location - any location at all.

You are not in control of the public IP address assignment at all but you are in control of traffic once it gets to that address.

Comment: Please explain why your opinion of feasibility is totally different from @ron-maupin's

Comment: See SuperUser [How are IP addresses assigned?](http://superuser.com/questions/151733/how-are-ip-addresses-assigned)

Comment: Got all that, thank you. But tell me how wouldn't it be possible for a foreign ISP to route a given IP to its network, if the RIR in charge of that IP (or network) agrees on that? Technically, what's the obstacle ?

Comment: It's not unlike telephone numbers.  If you want a telephone number in Africa to ring in Peru, you need to order a circuit (phone line w number) in Africa.  Then, using your equipment you ring a phone anywhere in the world when that number is called.  The calling user does not know the difference.  The number are given our by the carriers, just like IP addresses are.

Comment: Phone analogy is exactly why I don't get the "static circuit". Because most European ISP are AFAIK are using VoIP so your landline phone number isn't technically routed to your home but can virtually connected anywhere in the world if you have the credentials. I agree IP addresses aren't the same, but if IPs are routed in a country and cannot change, how can an ISP sell, for a French server (for instance) multiple country based IPs (but only European) to be routed to that same server?